# In T-SQL under MS SQL Server 2008, what does '@' mean in front of a parameter *value* that's a string literal?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have come across the following example code:

```
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_profileaccount_sp        
                            @profile_name = @'SQL mail profile',        
                            @account_name = @'account name',        
                            @sequence_number = 1 ;
```

What does '@' mean in front of the string literal, as in the example above:

```
@account_name=@'account name'
```

I understand that my question may stand true for any executable module's parameters in T-SQL, or maybe for any string literal in T-SQL in general, so the above is just a concrete example of what I'm looking at.

Comment: Where did you come across that code?

Comment: Got it from [SQLServerCentral](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/FindPost982744.aspx).

Comment: Hmm, odd, because the two answers here are right on the spot, that is not valid syntax in T-SQL. You *might* find someone that can shed some light on this over at [dba.se], but I don't think so. If you decide to post it there, you should make sure you copy out the relevant bits from that page you linked to in your comment, to avoid forcing people to go hunting for the code. But I agree, looks strange, and the way it is formatted seems to indicate it is a copy of existing code, I would assume it thus was tested.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: I have instead sent a PM on SQL Server Central to the OP, asking for the clarification, as he's a frequent visitor to that forum. I'll update this thread with the outcome of our message exchange.

Comment: I have just received an answer from the OP and he has confirmed that this, in fact is an error in the SQL script provided. So, the accepted answer below should stand.

Comment: It's probably supposed to be an 'N' - `@account_name=N'account name'` denoting a unicode literal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think that this is valid T-SQL.  This may be an artifact of replacing variables with values somewhere in a script and not trimming the leading @.

Comment: That was my thought also, plus SSMS didn't like the syntax and I found nothing to this effect in BOL, so I'm going to accept this answer.

Answer (score 2):

I get a syntax error with that, so I don't think it means anything except that it's not valid syntax. Did you pull that from valid T-SQL that is being called using just T-SQL, or perhaps this is parameterized stuff coming from some other language or program?

Comment: It's getting generated via dynamic SQL. Please see my comment to @Lasse V. Karlsen above for the source link

Comment: --entirely possible and I would agree, I was put off by the seemingly deliberate placement of the @ character in the code snippet.